# union of bounded set and its boundary is sequentially compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $K$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $K \cup \delta K$ is sequentially compact, Where $\delta K$ is boundary of $K$.
Now we know that $\delta K$ is compact since $K$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how can I proceed from here. Is there any rule for union of bounded and compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $K \cup \delta K=\bar{K}$ which is compact in $R^n$ since $K$ is bounded thus sequentially compact.

Indeed $\bar{K}=K^o \cup \delta K \subseteq K \cup \delta K \subseteq \bar{K}$